# How Can I Check isNaN in Angular2 Expression?

Tags: angular

When I'm trying to do this:

```
dividerColor="{{isNaN(+price) ? 'warn' : 'primary'}}"
```

It gives me this error:

```
browser_adapter.ts:82 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: self.context.isNaN is not a function
```

How can I check if my object is a not number in Angular2 expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the expressions are evaluated against view context, not with `eval`, JS globals are unavailable in templates.

Considering that [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) was polyfilled, technically it can be done with

```
{{ (+price).constructor.isNaN(+price) ... }}
```

Though it can be considered a hack. I would suggest to expose each and every helper function as either class property or a pipe.

Comment: When I try, dividerColor="{{(+price).constructor.isNaN(+price) ? 'warn' : 'primary'}}", it gives me this error: browser_adapter.ts:82 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: self._NgModel_74_7.constructor.isNaN is not a function. Do you have like plunkr or something else that I can test with?

Comment: I think it's best to just add a method to your component `isNan(val) { return isNan(val); }` and use it in binding like you do in your question.

Comment: @Vicheanak The answer explicitly states that Number.isNaN [needs to be polyfilled, it is ES6 feature](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/library/fn/number/is-nan.js). It won't work without a polyfill. And it work with a polyfill. As it was already said, a cleaner way to do this is to expose `isNaN` heper function as class method.

Comment: why not simple `{{price==+price? 'warn' : 'primary'}}`?

Comment: @PaoloCasciello It does, https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-boyd-gt7er . Still may be not a good idea to do this in a template.

Comment: @Eliseo It doesn't check if it's NaN. But `{{+price!==+price? 'warn' : 'primary'}}` does.

Comment: @EstusFlask i admit o tried it only in console.. sorry.

Answer (score 17):

You can expose the function as a property of the class:

```
class MyComponent {
  isNaN: Function = Number.isNaN;
}

<div>dividerColor="{{isNaN(+price) ? 'warn' : 'primary'}}"</div>
```

Comment: do we need to import this "Number"?

Comment: No, it's native JS Number

Answer (score 6):

### Other answers are not the best way to do it

Other answers suggests to create a component function to check whether the value is NaN like:

```
*ngIf="myCustomIsNaN(value)"
```

This approach **is**, as far as I know, **a problem in Angular** because you're calling a function to check the value. So the change detector will continue to call that function to check if the value returned changed.
If you put a console.log in that function you'll see it is called 1 to 10 times a second thus re rendering the template.

I think the only *good* way to do this is to use a custom Pipe.

### Why is the Pipe a better solution

Consider the following template code:

```
<div *ngIf="value | isNan"> ... </div>
```

In this case the change detector trigger a re rendering **only** if `value` changes. And **then** it evaluates the `ngIf` statement and re renders the template accordingly.

Less calls, less renderings, less cpu utilization, more performance. :)

### The Pipe code

For elegance in templates I created two pipes to check NaNs: `isNaN` and `isNotNaN`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Pipe to return true if the number is NaN
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'isNaN'
})
export class IsNaNPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(item: number): boolean {
    return isNaN(item);
  }
}

/**
 * Pipe to return true if the number is NOT NaN
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'isNotNaN'
})
export class IsNotNaNPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(item: number): boolean {
    return !isNaN(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of exposing the isNan function in the component and to apply some rule in the template, I think that it would be a better choice to expose a property having a business meaning.
For example :

```
class MyComp {
  hasPrice: boolean;
  someAction() {
    ...
    this.hasPrice = !isNaN(this.item.price);
  }
}

<div dividerColor="{{hasPrice ? 'warn' : 'primary'}}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be considered a hack, but it is really simple to use in a template.
`NaN` is so special that it is different from everything and even from itself, that is (`NaN == NaN`)  is always `false`.

So this will do the job:

```
dividerColor = "{{price !== price? 'warn': 'primary'}}"
```

Nothing is different from itself except `NaN`.